# How to get all SSRS reports from Sharepoint url?

Tags: c#, wpf, sharepoint, ssrs-2008

I'm very new to SSRS and SharePoint, We deployed the reports in SharePoint location, often some of the Reports doesn't have connection string.
For this in order to ensure, I need to get all reports from SharePoint location using c# WPF and check the connection strings of all the reports.

Answer (score 1):

I believe all of the SSRS versions after 2005 have a SOAP web service that can be accessed and provide what you need. C# should be able to read that (or you can render client side if it's faster for you to code). The GetDataSourceContents is the element to look for. [Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.getdatasourcecontents(v=sql.100).aspx) the 2008 documentation for that.

You can find Microsoft's full end point specs for 2008 [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153580(v=sql.100).aspx). There should be a directory with reportservice2008.asmx (or ...2006 for SharePoint if you believe [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7f87eff8-1d14-4ddc-bb48-160e01753af1/reportservice2008asmxwsdl-is-not-found-in-add-web-refrence-option?forum=sqlreportingservices) discussion). [Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169816(v=sql.100).aspx) the documentation on how to add the service reference to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a piece of code that i think it might work for you

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Handles frequently used functionalities in ReportViewer Controls to display SSRS reports locally.
    /// </summary>
    public class SSRSReport
    {
        private static String GetReportServerURL()
        {
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();

        //Execute the stored procedure to get the Report Server URL from the database.
            DBConnect.FillDataTable("GetSSRSReportServerURL", datatable, null);
            if (datatable == null || datatable.Rows.Count == 0)
                return null;
            else
                return datatable.Rows[0]["PARAMETER_VALUE"].ToString().Trim();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Open the SSRS report based on the name of the report specified.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reportViewer">ReportViewer 
        /// object used to render the SSRS report on screen.</param>
        /// <param name="reportPath">Name of the Report 
        /// (.rdl) data uploaded on the server.</param>
        public static void DisplayReport(ReportViewer reportViewer, String reportPath)
        {
            try
            {
                reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
                ServerReport serverreport = reportViewer.ServerReport;
                ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                ReportServerCredentials rscredentials = serverreport.ReportServerCredentials;
                rscredentials.NetworkCredentials = credentials;
                serverreport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(GetReportServerURL());
                serverreport.ReportPath = reportPath;

                reportViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
                reportViewer.ShowPrintButton = true;

                reportViewer.Refresh();
                reportViewer.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Open the SSRS report based on the name of the report and Report Parameters specified.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reportViewer">ReportViewer 
        /// object used to render the SSRS report on screen.</param>
        /// <param name="reportPath">Name of the Report 
        /// (.rdl) data uploaded on the server.</param>
        /// <param name="reportParameterList">
        /// List of Report parameters.</param>
        public static void DisplayReport(ReportViewer reportViewer, 
            String reportPath, List<ReportParameter> reportParameterList)
        {
            try
            {
                reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
                ServerReport serverreport = reportViewer.ServerReport;

                ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                ReportServerCredentials rscredentials = serverreport.ReportServerCredentials;
                rscredentials.NetworkCredentials = credentials;
                serverreport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(GetReportServerURL());
                serverreport.ReportPath = reportPath;

                reportViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
                reportViewer.ShowPrintButton = true;

                if (reportParameterList != null)
                {
                    foreach (ReportParameter param in reportParameterList)
                    {
                        serverreport.SetParameters(param);
                    }
                }

                reportViewer.Refresh();
                reportViewer.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert the SSRS report on the local report viewer to an Attachment. 
        /// This can be used to attach the PDF to an email.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reportViewer">ReportViewer control.</param>
        /// <param name="fileName">Name of the PDF data.</param>
        /// <returns>PDF File as an Attachment that 
        /// can be attached to an email using SMTPClient.</returns>
        public static Attachment ConvertToPDFAttachment(ReportViewer reportViewer, String fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] data;
                if (reportViewer.ServerReport != null)
                    data = reportViewer.ServerReport.Render("PDF");
                else
                    data = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF");
                Attachment att = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(data), fileName);
                return att;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Saves the report from the local reportViewer as PDF. 
        /// To execute this method, the reportviewer needs to already contain the SSRS report.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reportViewer">ReportViewer 
        /// control that displays the report.</param>
        /// <param name="filePath">Path of the file 
        /// to which the report should be stored as PDF.</param>
        /// <returns>True,if saved successfully ; False,otherwise.</returns>
        public static Boolean SaveAsPDF(ReportViewer reportViewer, String filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] data;
                if (reportViewer.ServerReport != null)
                    data = reportViewer.ServerReport.Render("PDF");
                else
                    data = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF");

                FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                fs.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Saves the report from the SSRS Report Server as PDF.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reportViewer">ReportViewer 
        /// control that displays the report.</param>
        /// <param name="filePath">Path of the file 
        /// to which the report should be stored as PDF.</param>
        /// <param name="reportPath">Name of the Report 
        /// (.rdl) data uploaded on the server.</param>
        /// <returns>True,if saved successfully ; False,otherwise.</returns>
        public static Boolean SaveAsPDF(ReportViewer reportViewer, String filePath, String reportPath)
        {
            try
            {
                DisplayReport(reportViewer, reportPath);
                byte[] data;
                if (reportViewer.ServerReport != null)
                    data = reportViewer.ServerReport.Render("PDF");
                else
                    data = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF");

                FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                fs.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Saves the report from the SSRS Report Server as PDF.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reportViewer">ReportViewer 
        /// control that displays the report.</param>
        /// <param name="filePath">Path of the file 
        /// to which the report should be stored as PDF.</param>
        /// <param name="reportPath">Name of the Report 
        /// (.rdl) data uploaded on the server.</param>
        /// <param name="reportParameterList">List of Report parameters.</param>
        /// <returns>True,if saved successfully ; False,otherwise.</returns>
        public static Boolean SaveAsPDF(ReportViewer reportViewer, 
            String filePath, String reportPath, List<ReportParameter> reportParameterList)
        {
            try
            {
                DisplayReport(reportViewer, reportPath,reportParameterList);
                byte[] data;
                if (reportViewer.ServerReport != null)
                    data = reportViewer.ServerReport.Render("PDF");
                else
                    data = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF");

                FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                fs.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

how this class can be used:

```
public class SSRSReportViewer
{
private ReportViewer _reportViewer;

//Display Report with NO parameters.
SSRSReport.DisplayReport(_reportViewer, ReportPath);

//Display Report WITH Parameters.
List<ReportParameter> paramList = new List<ReportParameter>();
paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("param1", param1);
paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("param2", param2);
SSRSReport.DisplayReport(_reportViewer, ReportPath ,paramList);

//Convert the Report to PDF Attachment.
//This Attachment object can be used along with SMTPClient 
//object to send the report as a PDF attachment with an email.
Attachment att = SSRSReport.ConvertToPDFAttachment(this._reportViewer, fileName);

//Save Report with NO parameters already displayed on the reportViewer as PDF.
SSRSReport.SaveAsPDF(_reportViewer, filePath);

//Save Report with NO Parameters as PDF without displaying it in the ReportViewer.
SSRSReport.SaveAsPDF(_reportViewer, filePath, ReportPath);

//Save the Report WITH parameters as PDF.
SSRSReport.SaveAsPDF(_reportViewer, filePath, ReportPath, paramList);
}
```

[Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/699869/Accessing-SSRS-Reports-from-SharePoint-Site-using)

Comment: no, this is not what I expect,
1.I need to fetch all the reports from sharepoint.
2. I need see the connection strings of all the reports that are fetched. 
eg: Imagine the grid with two columns report name and Connection strrings.

Comment: You might consider a different approach and run SQL queries to get the results you are looking for . Check out this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182005(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

#### as already well said, easier way is using webservice :

- case 1 : *you want to list all report*

  - use "CatalogItem()" service
  - display in whatever you want and let user choose
- case 2 : *you know exactly which report to launch or user choosed (by clicking element for instance) one to display*

  - then it is simple call:
    `http://YOUR_REPORTING_SERVER_URL?/PATH_TO_SPECIFIC_REPORT/REPORT_NAME&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=EXCEL&ADDITIONNAL_PARAMETER1=VALUE`

*Note : rs:Format is here configured to export Excel (you can also define pdf etc...). Let reporting service do the job for you.* Don't want to export, skip this parameter to open reporting service in navigation explorer.